# How does string formatting work in a spark.sql statement in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with Pyspark and am writing a query using spark.sql. I want to choose values from an array declared somewhere else to avoid having to type in names of all rows again.

Here is my attempt but this does not work.

```
array_fields = ["cat", "dog"]  
ans= spark.sql("""select {} from <table_name>.format(",".join[array_fields]) """)
```

I've also tried

```
 ans= spark.sql("""select {} from <table_name> """).format(",".join[array_fields])
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your examples are correct as you have actually tried them, your use of format and join are not quite right.

Try:

```py
array_fields = ["cat", "dog"]  
ans= spark.sql("""select {} from <table_name> """.format(",".join(array_fields)))
```

The differences are:

1. The format method is applied to the string you are wanting to format.
2. The join method is a function call - it's parameter should be in round brackets, not square brackets (your 2nd example).
3. The join method is not part of the string (your 1st example).

You might also - in the first instance - try using print rather than calling `spark.sql` directly. That is:

```py
array_fields = ["cat", "dog"]  
print("""select {} from <table_name> """.format(",".join(array_fields)))
```

That way you can see what you will ultimately be passing to Spark. when you are ready, simply replace `print` with `ans = spark.sql` and away you go.

Comment: Hey I tried to use the same logic for IN filtering operation but not sure how to pass the tuple within the list let's say if we want to filter on only cat and dog, any thoughts would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is the format required? Try to use f-string.

```py
f"""SELECT {",".join(array_fields)} FROM <table_name>"""
```